# Memory Game - hide img - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a memory game in jQuery, but I'm struggeling with hiding the elements
That's my html body:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="size" id="4x4" value="16">
    <label for="4x4">4x4</label>

    <input type="radio" name="size" id="4x6" value="24">
    <label for="4x6">4x6</label>

    <input type="radio" name="size" id="6x6" value="36">
    <label for="6x6">6x6</label>

    <input type="button" value="Start" id="start">

    <div id="memoryField">
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The pictures are working fine. The problem is that I should only be able to see two pictures at a time, when I click on a third picture, the two last ones should be invisible again.

I tried it with a time out, but didn't work the way I wanted.
And the second problem is, that I would like to hide the div's with the images in it, this also doesn't work.

That's my js-code:

```
let cards = $("input:radio[name = 'size']:checked").val();
let amountClicked = 0;
let clicks = 0;
$("#memoryField div").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        if ($("img", this).hasClass("hidden")) {
            $("img", this).removeClass("hidden");
            $("img", this).addClass("visible");
            amountClicked++;
            clicks++;

            if (amountClicked == 2) {
                if (($("img", last).attr("src") != $("img", this).attr("src")) && $("img", last).hasClass("visible")) {
                    let that = $(this);
                    window.setTimeout(function (that) {
                        $("img", last).removeClass("visible");
                        $("img", last).addClass("hidden");
                        $("img", that).removeClass("visible");
                        $("img", that).addClass("hidden");
                        amountClicked = 0;
                    }, 800);
                } else {
                    let that = $(this);
                    window.setTimeout(function (that) {

                        $("img", that).parent().hide();
                        $("img", last).parent().hide();
                        amountClicked = 0;
                        cards -= 2;
                    }, 500);
                }
            }
        }
        last = $(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have my attention, but first, you don't need to use $("#memoryField div").each(function () , simply use $("#memoryField div").click(function) will do
I can't test out your code because does not have js after click "start" button,
But if I'm working on this task, I will make everything very simplify to somthing like this:

```
let amountClicked = 0;
$("#memoryField div").click(function() {
    if ($("img", this).hasClass("hidden")) {
        if (amountClicked == 2) {
            $("#memoryField div img").removeClass("visible"); // Remove other img visible class
            $("#memoryField div img").addClass("hidden");
            amountClicked = 0; // Reset
        }

        $("img", this).removeClass("hidden");
        $("img", this).addClass("visible");

        amountClicked++;
    }
});
```

It should work

Comment: Also, if you can't trigger the click function, you can use $(document).on('click', '#memoryField div', function() {

Comment: thank god it did work! Thank you so much
Now I still need the check if they are the same pictures